# Python try_decorator to retry i2c connections

Tags: python, decorator

I am communicating with some hardware over an I2C bus.

Every so often, there is an exception as the bus is busy so I am currently handling this with a loop that retries, but there's a lot of code repetition, I want to tidy it up.

So, I tried to write a decorator function to pass various functions to

As an example, this command initialises the bus:
 `i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)`

This is the decorator I have written:

```
def try_decorator(func, name):
    MAX_TRIES = 5
    i = 1
    n = name
    while True:
        try:
            func()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'retry {i} for {n}')
            i += 1
            if i == MAX_TRIES:
                print(f'max retries of {MAX_TRIES} reached for {n}, with error: {e}')
                break
            continue
        break
```

And then I try to pass it the line mentioned above as a partial:
`i2c = try_decorator(partial(busio.I2C, board.SCL, board.SDA), 'i2c init')` but I get an exception when I then try and pass the i2c to the next function: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'try_lock'` which I think means the partial isn't actually initialising the bus properly.  I also tried as a lambda and as a function but get similar results.

What can I do to fix this and keep my code as straightforward as possible?

Also, instead of passing a string as `name` as an arg (to track exceptions), I tried using func.**name** in the decorator when I tried as a function instead of a partial but it gives an error that seems as if it is trying to get the name of the I2C object.

Edit: I have updated my code as per BigBro's answer to below but I still get an error when passing the i2c object to my next function (I don't get this error if I run without the decorator).

```
def retry(f):
    MAX_TRIES = 5
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(MAX_TRIES):
            try:
                res = f(*args, **kwargs)
                return res
            except IOError as e:
                print(f'retry {i} for {f.__name__}, with error: {e}')
        print(f'max retries of {MAX_TRIES} reached for {f.__name__}, with error: {e}')
    return wrapped

i2c = retry(busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA))

drv = adafruit_drv2605.DRV2605(i2c)
```

`'function' object has no attribute 'try_lock'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you forgot to return the result of the function in `try_decorator` (and therefore return `None`). Replace `func()` with `res = func()` and then `return res` at the end.

However your function is not really a decorator, as it doesn't actually return a function, and can't be used as `@try_decorator`.

I would suggest something like:

```py
import random

MAX_RETRIES = 10
def retry_decorator(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):  # Allows arg to be passed to the function instead of using partial
        for i in range(MAX_RETRIES):
            try:
                res = f(*args, **kwargs)
                return res
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Function {f.__name__} failed {i}/{MAX_RETRIES}: {e}')  # f.__name__ is what you're looking for
        print(f'Function {f.__name__} didn\'t work after {MAX_RETRIES} retries: {e}')
    return wrapped


@retry_decorator
def fail_randomly():
    i = random.randint(0, 10)
    if i < 7:
        raise RuntimeError('Random error')
    print('Sucess!')

fail_randomly()
```

output

```py
Function fail_randomly failed 0/10: Random error
Function fail_randomly failed 1/10: Random error
Function fail_randomly failed 2/10: Random error
Function fail_randomly failed 3/10: Random error
Function fail_randomly failed 4/10: Random error
Sucess!
```

One last thing, I suggest being more specific in what exception you catch otherwise things might become hard to debug ;)

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give it a try a bit later. I thought I’d tried to return but must’ve missed something else at the time! Should this work with a partial too?

Comment: Sorry ignore that, silly question, I realised what I need to do. Cheers!

Comment: I made some changes but still got an error.  I have updated the bottom of my question. Thanks

Comment: Again I think you misunderstand how decorators work. The `retry` function is passed a function as argument and returns a function. So you have two choice to us it: either define a decorated function like: 
`@retry
def my_I2C(scl, sda):
    return busio.I2C(scl, sda)
i2c = my_I2C(busio.SCL, busio.SDA)`
Or simply
`i2c = retry(busio.I2C)(busio.SCL, busyio.SDA)`. Have a look at this [nice tutorial](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) to understand more clearly how it works.

Comment: Great, thanks, I wanted to call without creating another function so `obj = decorator(function)(args)` is what I needed.  That's the first time I've seen that syntax with double parentheses but I suppose it is because `decorator(function)` returns `wrapped` so it is effectively `wrapped(args)`. Is that correct?

Comment: You got it ;) if you want to make it more explicit you can do it in two steps: `i2c_getter = retry(busio.I2C)` and then `i2c = i2c_getter(busio.SCL, busio.SDA)`.